Theorem 7.5 of Atiyah and Macdonald

(Hilbert’s Basis Theorem). If $A$ is Noetherian, then the polynomial ring $A[x]$ is Noetherian.
Proof. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal in $A[x]$. $$\vdots$$ Let $M$ be the $A$-module generated by $1,x,…,x^{r-1}$; then what we have proved is that $\mathfrak{a}=(\mathfrak{a}\cap M)+ \mathfrak{a}’$. Now $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, hence is Noetherian by (6.5), hence $\mathfrak{a}\cap M$ is finitely generated (as an $A$-module) by (6.2). If $g_1,…,g_m$ generate $\mathfrak{a} \cap M$ it is clear that the $f_i$ and the $g_j$ generate $\mathfrak{a}$. Hence $\mathfrak{a}$ is finitely generated and so $A[x]$ is Noetherian.

Here $\mathfrak{a}’$ is ideal in $A[x]$ is generated by $f_1,…,f_n$, that is, $\mathfrak{a}’=A[x]f_1+\cdots +A[x]f_n$. We showed $\mathfrak{a}\cap M$ is finitely generated by $g_1,…,g_m$ as an $A$-module, that is, $\mathfrak{a}\cap M=Ag_1+\cdots +Ag_m$. So we have $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq (f_i,g_j)$, ideal generated by $f_i,g_j$. How to show equality holds?

This (first proof) is alternative easy proof of Hilbert’s basis theorem.

All of the $f_i$ and $g_j$ were chosen to be elements of $\mathfrak{a}$. Therefore, the ideal they generate will be a subset of $\mathfrak{a}$.

Thank you for the answer. I knew it was simple, but wasn’t able to see.
